# Apache MINA SFTP symlinks example

Tags: java, sftp, apache-mina, apache-sshd

I'm trying to set up an `SFTP` server using `apache sshd` with multiple users that each have their own home directory. We wanted grant the access to folders to multiple users using the symbolic links.

Can someone please tell me how to do this ?

I tried the alternative to symbolic links by using the mount option but the entry of every mount in `mtab` file gets deleted on reboot/restart the machine.

Comment: is it possible to access the symlinks in SFTP ?

Comment: Well *"access symlink"* is rather vague term. You can *resolve symlink location* using SFTP, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Okay. Can you please suggest any solution to resolve symlink location ?

Comment: Consider user with home directory /home/TEST. 
Under that symlinks are present e.g. Folder1 -> /home/user/Folder1.
Once I clicked to Folder1 is must show the contents of "/home/user/Folder1" folder